# C# AsyncでWEB画像を複数枚ダウンロード

Tags: c#, 非同期

C# AsyncでWEB画像を複数枚ダウンロードする時の非同期の書き方ってこちらで合っていますか？
for文がどうも変だと思うのですが。

```
private async void DownloadImage(string []uri, string path)
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    for (int i = 0; i < uri.Length; i++)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage res = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri[i], HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

        using (var fileStream = File.Create(path+(i+1)+".jpg"))
        {
            using (var httpStream = await res.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
                httpStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                fileStream.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`await`の時点でその操作の完了を待ってしまいます。
並列にダウンロードしたい場合は、１つ１つのダウンロードを行う`Task`を用意しそれを`Task.WhenAll()`で待つ必要があります。

```
static async Task DownloadImage(HttpClient httpClient, string uri, string path) {
    using (var res = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
    using (var fileStream = File.Create(path))
    using (var httpStream = await res.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        await httpStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
}

static async Task DownloadImage(string[] uris, string path) {
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        await Task.WhenAll(uris.Select((uri, i) => DownloadImage(httpClient, uri, string.Format("{0}{1}.jpg", path, i + 1))));
}
```

こまごまと指摘があります。

- 全てのダウンロードの完了を知るためにも戻り値は`Task`の方がいいでしょう。
- `ReadAsStreamAsync()`は読み取り開始でしかなくダウンロード全体に関しては`CopyTo()`部分も`CopyToAsync()`にすべきです。
- `IDisposable`に関しては`using`などで全て`Dispose()`しておくべきです。
- `FileStream`は`using`してあれば`Fluash()`不要です。
- `using`をネストする際、括弧を書かなければインデントが深くなりません。

Comment: usingのこのような使い方が存じませんでした。
Taskは勉強不足でした。大変助かりました。